# What Data Format Exchange uses * and # instead of tags brackets?

Tags: asp.net, xml, json, asp-classic, data-exchange

There is a Web Service that returns this XML as a result for a GET.
I want to know is this a famous Data Exchange Format ? or it just needs to be parsed normally ?
or should I replace the * and # with normal brackets and handle it as a normal XML ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Count=56,*ProjectDataSet#
  *Project#
    *PROJ_UID#f6f08258-52dd-481a-83a5-013cce51d901*/PROJ_UID#
    *PROJ_NAME#5-2 Disaster Recovery site*/PROJ_NAME#
    *DVI#0*/DVI#
  */Project#
  *Project#
    *PROJ_UID#7abd8857-2a9a-4d2d-82c3-139fdac26994*/PROJ_UID#
    *PROJ_NAME#4-1 Automated Land Releasing System Phase II*/PROJ_NAME#
    *DVI#0*/DVI#
  */Project#
*/ProjectDataSet# ###Duration: 00:00:24.5568479</string>
```

Comment: Looks to me like this is straight xml that was somehow escaped with "*" equal to "<" and "#" equal to ">".  I haven't seen this before.

Comment: that's the case, probably by generation via xslt ever tried to generate xml through xslt that gives pain in the head, this is prob. the work-around

Comment: @swannee Yes but I think the last line is an exception that ###Duration: 00:00:24 ...  thing.

Comment: @Paul could you provide for me more details please ? or a link that i can search for it ?

Comment: @Belbesy, just replace the * with a < and the # with an >
I truly think someone was having a hard-time generating correct XML, so this was an escape... of the webservice programmer... that leaves u with the sh*t to make it more robust: if this is all xml it would be wiser to replace *Project# with <Project> etc... and not to use a global wild card replace